# How can I fill an existing PDF with data of an android app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, pdf

I have an simple Android App, where I can add text to the edittext and dann this data is transfered to an SQLlite Database. 
Now I want to have a button, that transfers the data from the database into the PDF file. Its important to have it in certain spots in the PDF.

Is there a way to do this all, maybe even with Java?

Comment: Yes there are ways to do it. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I have tried to rebuild the PDF with iText. But this isn't what I was really wanted. Also I tried to save the data to an txt and then insert them into the PDF manually.